# SQL Server email and I can't reach a few features

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

I've been doing this for 3 days. I couldn't find the solution. Normally it was supposed to have features like the following.

[image]

What is the cause of this problem? And how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using SQL Server Express. SQL Server Express is a very cut down version of SQL Server and does not provide anywhere near as many features as Standard and Enterprise; such as database mail ([Additional Database Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#ADS)). If you need features, you need to purchase SQL Server and pay for the edition licences that have the features you need.

If you are using SQL Server for **development** purposes only, you can use SQL Server Developer Edition, which is allowed to be used for non-production environments only. Developer edition has all of the features that Enterprise does.

You can find the full list of features supplied by each edition here: [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017)